# Hibernate-like framework for Actionscript-3

Tags: database, actionscript-3, hibernate, sqlite

With flash and SQLite being supported on the new tablets and smartphones.

Is there a database abstraction layer similar to hibernate for java but written in ActionScript3 that supports SQLite?

I would rather concentrate on the User Interface rather than the data services portions of the applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to checkout [FlexORM](http://flexorm.riaforge.org/). It hasn't seen much attention recently however it might be a good start.

A nice Adobe writeup on FlexORM: http://www.adobe.com/newsletters/edge/october2009/articles/article7/index.html?trackingid=EXBII